# How can I get international characters in mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, mailer

I would like my mailer action will send something like this:

```
==
==  Wiadomość testowa programu EZA (tekst)
==
```

Instead i got this (when used `default 'content-transfer-encoding' => 'base64'` in my ApplicationMailer):

```
WiadomotestowaprogramuEZAteksg==
```

when used `'7bit'`:

```
==
==  WiadomoM-EM^[M-DM^G testowa programu EZA (tekst)
==
```

when used `'8bit'`/`'quoted-printable'`:

```
=3D=3D
=3D=3D  Wiadomo=C5=9B=C4=87 testowa programu EZA (tekst)
=3D=3D
```

How to configure this gizmo to send international characters?

Comment: Have you tried UTF8?

Comment: I got this:

Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64


==
==  WiadomoM-EM^[M-DM^G testowa programu EZA (tekst)
==

Comment: Maybe I have to set other option also, not only **default 'content-transfer-encoding'**